# Which controller should I use?

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have knowledge of both UIViewController and UINavigationController.

But I am very confused about which to use and when?

Can anyone clear up my confusion?

Also please let me know if there is any difference in memory and speed of BOTH..

(I only know about their storage procedure that one supports heap and the other stack)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have different use cases:

UINavigationController might be the "base" controller for handling different levels of views, i.e. you start with a table view, push a detail view, push another detail view etc.

UIViewController or UITableViewController would be classes for the concrete views you push onto the navigation controller.